# Какие различия между findFirst и findAny в Java 8?

Tags: java, java-stream, функциональное-программирование, java-faq

Я не очень понимают отличие `findFirst()` от `findAny()` в Java Stream API.

Я думал, что `findFirst()` возвращает первый элемент стрима, а `findAny()` случайны элемент стрима.

Но когда я запускаю 2 примера кода:

`Stream.of(...).findFirst()` и `Stream.of(...).findAny()`

То они оба возвращают первый элемент стрима. Почему? Они оба делают одинаковую задачу?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35359112/difference-between-findany-and-findfirst-in-java-8

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Они оба делают одинаковую задачу?

Нет. Согласно JavaDoc [`Stream#findAny()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--):

> Возвращает `Optional<T>`, хранящий некоторый элемент стрима, или
>   пустой `Optional<T>`, если стрим пуст. Поведение этой операции не
>   определено - он может выбрать любой элемент в потоке. Это позволяет
>   обеспечить максимальную производительность при параллельных операциях;

Т.е., при непараллельном стриме он вернет первый элемент. А при параллельном стриме он может вернуть любой элемент.

Тогда как [`Stream#findFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) вернет `Optional<T>`, хранящий **строго первый** элемент потока.

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, здесь также имеет место недопонимание целей существования `Stream.of(...).findAny()`.
Использовать этот метод для генерации случайного значения наверное не стоит. Всё-таки предполагается, что этому методу будет предшествовать filter() с предикатом, который как-то сократит выборку и уже из этого отфильтрованного стрима будет взят любой (первый, пятый, какая разница, любой значит любой) элемент.